# Is Openwhisk still being actively developed?

Tags: openwhisk

I have used the openwhisk/standalone image from docker hub. Is that still current - the latest revision is from a few weeks ago but very little docs on the page.
There are many openwhisk repositories but little information about them - eg what is the difference between standalone, invoker and controller?

Answer (score 0):

> There are many openwhisk repositories but little information about them - eg what is the difference between standalone, invoker and controller?

You must be referring to the Docker repositories, not the git repositories. Each of these is a build off the git head for CI and testing.

The standalone image is used for running a lean OpenWhisk stack locally on one's machine. It requires no Kubernetes or other dependencies outside of docker. The other images (that are not runtime images) are used for a distributed deployment (e.g., for a Kubernetes or bare metal deployment) since each component is its own service.

A listing of all the source repositories is available on the website https://openwhisk.apache.org/documentation.html.

If you'd like to understand the OpenWhisk architecture it's also available at the above link.

And yes, the project is still active.